# Get Facebook User Email Using Graph API PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I'm Using a Graph API of Facebook with php i'm trying to get user information to login user to my site but after a lot of searching and reading i'm getting all my required data expect email.

```
<?php
include_once('../dashboard/includes/db_connection.php');
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '1393606834280204','3faf1ede6ccc48d6adf096f1a6850359' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://lhefficise.com/facebook/fbconfig.php' );
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email' );
    $response = $request->execute();
    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    // $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
    // $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
    // $fbfirstname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook First Name
    // $fblastname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook First Name
    // $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    $obj = $graphObject->asArray();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($obj);exit;
} else {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

i'm sending request for  `/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email` but i'm not getting email all other information is fine.

```
Array
(
    [id] => xxxxxxxxxx83xxxx
    [first_name] => Shan
    [last_name] => Khaliq
    [name] => Shan Khaliq
)
```

I might be doing something wrong while getting the record..

I already have permission for email check the link for that.

http://prntscr.com/9steek

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out just after i posted this.

`$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));`

i need to put scop to get login url from facebook.

guys Thanks i really appropriate who were upto this question.